# npm 2nd level dependency need to get 1st level dependency package.json (npm submodule dependency management)

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I am trying to develop a package to allow easy import of prebuilt modules.
So the use case i want to cover is project X uses prebuilt module Y so my module can provide easy creation of this prebuilt distribution through GitHub releases.
So i was expecting a structure of dependencies like this:

```
X
|-Y
  |-any-prebuilt
```

But i am currently ending up at my top level when importing with

```
X
|-Y
|-any-prebuilt
```

So npm and also yarn seem to be flattening out the structure out, as i can se my error on the postinstall of what i expected to be a 2nd level dependency.

```
bash-3.2$ npm install

> any-prebuilt@0.0.3 postinstall /Users/me/workspace/<X>/node_modules/any-prebuilt
> node install.js

Fetching prebuilt:
 version: latest

Platform: osx
Arch: x64
Target dir: ./bin
required user & repo
```

in this case I have 2 questions, what am i missing here? and also is it posible for my `any-prebuilt` get the `package.json` of `Y`?

https://github.com/kanekotic/any-prebuilt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i think i can now answer my own questions. Since npm version 3 the structure is by default flatten out (same for yarn), it will just be non flat in the case of clash of dependencies.

So for future people that end up here (if any) there are 2 options if you are the final project you could use a flag while running npm install.

```
npm install --legacy-bundling
```

In my case this is not a posibility so I had to modify my code to make it more API oriented. So the prebuilt packages that use my lib will actually have to provide the information.

I have passed the postinstall event one level up. so basicalle declare a `postbuild.js` file in `Y` that does:

```
require('any-prebuilt').install(require('./package.json').prebuilt)
```

So last advice do not add scripts that will require level up of information.

References:

https://codingwithspike.wordpress.com/2016/01/21/dealing-with-the-deprecation-of-peerdependencies-in-npm-3/

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install